# Reading Tableau data with Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a tableau server hosted on a remote server. There are some tables/views(in RDBMS) which are connected to Tableau for reports and dashboards.

Is there a way that I can connect to Tableau and read those tables ? 
If yes, then could you please provide a snippet of code where you are able to see data from a tableau view!

***Note: I don't want to read data from RDBMS. I want to read those tables/views directly from Tableau***

Comment: If you are working with a Tableau data source that has a published extract (as opposed to a live connection) then try Tableau’s new Hyper API

Comment: Why do you want to read the tableau data only? Do you want to check if the extract is refreshed, what is the purpose?

Comment: @JonathanLam , Reason: I want to read data populated in Tableau reports, extract data from the reports, and then compare it against the data in DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the data used by a Tableau view with the REST API endpoint [Query View Data](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_workbooksviews.htm#query_view_data).

Take a look at the Tableau Server Client library (python) method [views.populate_csv](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#viewspopulate_csv) which uses this API.